# Context SqlQuery<>() without detailing all columns

Tags: entity-framework

Let's say I have a `Person` entity with 3 columns:

```
public PERSON {
    public int OID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string SURNAME { get; set; }
}
```

I want to query it with raw SQL but without specifying all columns so I write:

```
var query = "select NAME, SURNAME from PERSON";
var list = context.SqlQuery<PERSON>(query).ToList();
```

But it throws Exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException : The data reader is incompatible with the specified '...'. A member of the type, 'OID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

So it seems like it tries to map all columns, and, if some are missing, it throws.

Is there a way to make it ignore columns that are not present in raw SQL query and map just the columns that are accessible?

The reason is, I have a lot of columns for some entities and sometimes I just want to query partial columns. I don't want to create new class with just the necessary columns for each query.

Comment: Why are you using `SqlQuery` instead of something like `var persons = from p in context.Persons select new PERSON { p.NAME, p.SURNAME};`?

Comment: I have a legacy system with a lot of already written SQL queries that are not so easy to rewrite in LINQ. So I'm looking for a way to deserialize those SQL query results to Entity classes.

Comment: In this case are you able to return a dummy value such as `SELECT 0 AS OID, NAME, SURNAME...`?

Comment: Even if I could, I have like 40-50 columns on Entity but I really need 2, writing "0 as X" is really not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 3 options off the top of my head that could work for you.

**Option 1:** Rewrite your queries and use a standard Linq query:

```
var persons = from p in context.Persons
              select new PERSON 
              {
                  NAME = p.NAME, 
                  SURNAME = p.SURNAME
              };
```

**Option 2:** Return a dummy value for columns you don't need

```
var query = "select 0 AS OID, NAME, SURNAME from PERSON";
var list = context.SqlQuery<AlmostPERSON>(query).ToList();
```

**Option 3:** Create your own intermediate classes with the columns you need from the database:

```
public class AlmostPERSON
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string SURNAME { get; set; }
}

var query = "select NAME, SURNAME from PERSON";
var list = context.SqlQuery<AlmostPERSON>(query).ToList();
```

You could even project this intermediate class onto your standard entity like this:

```
var list = context.SqlQuery<AlmostPERSON>(query)
                  .Select(ap => new PERSON 
                  {
                      NAME = ap.NAME,
                      SURNAME = ap.SURNAME
                  })
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Found one more possible solution: using ADO.NET IDataReader with AutoMapper

```
public List<T> ExecuteFor<T>(string sql)
{
  using (_connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
  {
    _connection.Open();
    using (var command = new OracleCommand(sql, _connection))
    {
         using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
              Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, List<T>>();
              return Mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<T>>(reader);
         }
    }                         
  }
}
```